# Add files to ng serve watch list

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 6 app that consists of multiple projects. Shared Components, Modules etc. are located in a Angular library.

I would like to add the dist folder of this library to the files that are being watched by ng serve so I don't manually have to rerun the watch command every time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran in this annoying issue, I think currently "ng serve" does not watch for library changes. Angular ClI guys know this and have plan to address this in future.

Meanwhile developing you can import following way in your app.modoule.ts to reload app whenever library changes.

```
import { MyLibraryModule} from 'projects/my-lirary/src/public_api';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, do you know if they fix the issue ? or if there is another work around ?

Comment: Not sure if this has been fixed. Haven’t checked it lately. As a workaround you can import your library like I mentioned above.